# Best Way to check ACTUAL space on SD/microSD card

Tags: filesystems, storage, sd-card

In the past I have read some posts by users that they have purchased a SD card from a generic vendor in another country.  Although the SD/microSD card may state that it holds 128GB/512GB, the actual storage space in practice is actually much smaller, sometimes only 1-8GB!

I just was offered a huge discount on a 128GB microSD card and before I use it in my devices I would like to check that it will not corrupt my files and I will not lose any data.

Theoretically, I think I could load it with a file 127GB or so in file size and see if that entire file gets corrupted.  Maybe the best choice of file would be a video file chopped and sized to 127GB....

But then again, I don't want to spend ...  20-30 HRS minimum copying this file to the SD card, and then the time to check / delete... and even where to find a video file 127GB in size.  Offhand that sounds like a 24hr+ movie!

I know there must be an easy way to ascertain the actual storage size of a SD/microSD card regardless of what the file index size states it is.

Can someone suggest the best way to go about testing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Disc management (Windows) or `disks` (Debian and derivatives) will show you the usable space. If you format it with full sector checking, this will confirm that the whole space is accessible.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution to me!  Thanks - wanna put it in the answer field so I can acknowledge?

Comment: If there's only 1~8 gigs on a 128GB card, you've been had. I'd throw it away on principle; who knows what could be embedded in it (not that it probably has 100 gigs of malware on it; just that there's already something fishy going on here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disc management (Windows) or `disks` (Debian and derivatives) will show you the usable space. There are also command-line utilities `diskpart` (Windows interactive program: use `list disk`) and `sudo fdisk -l` (Linux) to show the same information.

If you format it with full sector checking, this will confirm that the whole space is accessible.